# Plotting two different kind of plots next to each other (Seaborn, FacetGrid)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

So I have been working on a dataset and have to plots which I would like to plot next to each other with Seaborn. Unfortunately, using the FacetGrid function I am only able to plot the same kind next to each other.

I hope you guys can help me solve my problem and thank you in advance

[image: the first plot]
[[image: the second plot[2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `catplot()` which is [a figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html?highlight=catplot#seaborn.catplot) that creates a new FacetGrid each time, instead use the underlying axes-level functions [`barplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html#seaborn.barplot) and [`pointplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot)

i.e.:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.barplot(..., ax=ax1)
sns.pointplot(..., ax=ax2)
```